# GitLab keeps deleting my new branches

Tags: gitlab

Seemingly both GitLab and gitlab-mirrors are setup and working correctly for me. However not long after I create a new branch under username Admin using the default root account for example (not to be confused with the gitmirror user created not long after), I'll read in the commit history that the admin user deleted the branch entirely. Typically an hour later.

Prior to the new branch being deleted, everything seems 100%, and it is really cool to see my branch alongside the history of previous commits to the repo I mirrored, using git-mirror.

To be more clear, I am using gitmirror to pull a GitHub-hosted repo to GitLab. This repo already has two branches, one is called master (which is HEAD) and I can see those fine. The next thing I do is create a new branch for my own development as the Admin user, and while it seems to work just fine. Within an hour the log will read that the Admin user deleted the newly created branch (which happens every time automatically, and I certainly didn't do this manually myself).

I've checked cron, and it seems ok. During setup, as the gitmirror user I used 'crontab e' to install the following text (tweaked for my own domain of course):

```
Host gitlab.example.com
    User git
```

Since the machine is a virtual machine, it is easy to save snapshots which I've done. So it is possible to recover a snapshot with all the changes described, and I can watch the Admin user automatically delete my new branch not long after restoration (because the snapshot was saved hours ago already); which is handy for debugging purposes.

Should I not be creating repos using the default GitLab root account? Is there a log somewhere that shows more than the recent GIT history on the GitLab projects page? What else can I try?

I've created two different servers from scratch using the latest software versions now, and I get identical results on each.